# How to return the original color after painting?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I use the setThemingColor method to paint the element I need in the color I need, but I don’t know what method I should use to return the painted element to its original state, i.e. to blend the color in which it was painted.
I would be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#clearthemingcolors-model) which clears all theming color:

```
viewer.clearThemingColors()
```

However this is nothing out of the box to clear the theming color of a specific fragment. Stay tuned to our Forge Blog for future versions that might address this.